# Push github repository to railway.app not working

Tags: javascript, github

so I tried to push my github repository (discord bot) to railway.app and I am getting the following error:

```
==========================
Using Buildpacks!
==========================
20: Pulling from heroku/buildpacks
Digest: sha256:44cdda5b3d607a632391d5c2867ce99dff6f4461cc88047a2062807423984188
Status: Image is up to date for heroku/buildpacks:20
20: Pulling from heroku/pack
Digest: sha256:ff798f85873ca53848feb40563ff19d95ee96ce956630c8cbf9417e04b6a181b
Status: Image is up to date for heroku/pack:20
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/railway-infra/railway-docker-users/project/b33a432c-eca7-4896-b1e7-4659840475cd/service/c4a1bc85-ef3f-4670-9d54-64fe7ef5441f:f47f0d95-6f55-4fa6-8106-0933ae634a8d" not found
===> DETECTING
heroku/nodejs-engine 0.7.5
heroku/nodejs-npm    0.4.5
heroku/procfile      0.6.2
===> RESTORING
===> BUILDING
Node.js Buildpack
Installing toolbox
- yj
[Installing Node]
Getting Node version
Resolving Node version
Downloading and extracting Node v16.14.0
Setting NODE_ENV to production
[Parsing package.json]
Parsing package.json
No file to start server
either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
Using npm v8.3.1 from Node
Installing node modules from ./package-lock.json
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm
ERR!     /home/heroku/.npm/_logs/2022-02-28T23_33_55_496Z-debug-0.log
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 51
```

I have tried the "npm install" command as mentioned above, but I still get the same error, it's not working. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a `package-lock.json` file in your project (as in on your local PC)?

Comment: Yes, I just fixed the issue. I have another error I can show you if you want but idk if you want to do it

Comment: If you have another, error, please create a **new** question. I'll be happy to help there.

Comment: Alright, creating one now

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes, I'll create it in 90 minutes

Comment: Ah ok no problem then.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I fixed the issue. My issue was that after changing the code I did not commit the so it made sense why I kept getting the same error. Thanks to the ones who have viewed it though!